# Adobe Edge Animate Creating a slideshow with imagecount playing automoaically

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

My stage's `compositionready` has this code

```
//Variable
imageCount = 1;
```

and I have two buttons.

```
imageCount++;

sym.$("photo").attr("src","images/photo_"+imageCount+".jpg");
```

How can I manipulate the code so that the image count will automatically count up with a set time of (3 secsonds) without having to click the button each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to update an image every 3 seconds as a slideshow, if that is the case check the code below.

Here the `myOtherFunction` is being called every 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds),

```
var imageCount = 1;
var myVar = setInterval(myOtherFunction, 3000);

function myOtherFunction() {
    sym.$("photo").attr("src","images/photo_"+imageCount+".jpg");
    imageCount++;
}
```